# Как правильно составить запрос с where?

Tags: oracle, sql, база-данных

Данный запрос не работает. Почему?

```
Select id,name_column as name from test_table where name='test'
```

Выдает ошибку "недопустимый идентификатор".
т.е. если запрос будет вида:

```
Select id,(select count(*) from test_table)as tmp_col from test_table where tmp_col>1
```

то он тоже не будет работать. Как победить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что в WHERE нельзя использовать `ALIAS name_column AS name`.
Вам необходимо писать `name_column = 'test'`.

Comment: Ок, тогда как быть с 

    Select id,(select count(*) from test_table)as tmp_col from test_table where tmp_col>1 

Как отсюдо достать count?

Comment: Так:

     Select id,(select count(*) from test_table)as tmp_col from test_table where (select count(*) from test_table)>1

Comment: Мне кажется, правильно так:

    Select id, tmp_col
    from (Select id, (select count() from test_table) as tmp_col from test_table) as outerTable
    where tmpl_col > 1

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, нужно получить id из таблицы, если в ней больше одной записи (по крайней мере без группировки выглядит именно так). В таком случае, корректнее использовать такой код.

```
select x.id
from test_table x
where exists (select 1
  from test_table y
  where y.id != x.id
);
```

Использование count(*) для того, чтобы узнать, что есть там что-то или нет, неправильно. Лучше сразу делать то, что нужно, а при необходимости обрабатывать exception.